# Teamcity - How to Build a multi project Visual Studio solution?

Tags: teamcity

I have a Visual Studio 2013 solution with multiple projects in it. (Source code is in SVN)

Here is the project/solution structure

**d:\src\Service\MyService\MyService.sln**

This above solution contains 2 projects. The file path for both projects are,

- **d:\src\Service\MyService\MyServiceProject\MyServiceProject.csproj**  - For simplicity let's call this - Project A
- **d:\src\Library\MyLibrary\MyLibraryProject\MyLibraryProject.csproj**  - For simplicity let's call this - Project B

Here, project Project A has a project reference to Project B

I have configured TeamCity to use default Visual Studio build (ie., I have no custom MSBuild scripts) to build the MyService.sln.

When I build the project in TeamCity, the build fails saying that it could not find the .dll file that was supposed to be produced by Project B.

I checked the TeamCity working directory and I don't see Project B's source code at all. What am I missing here?

Comment: what is your cvs root set up to check out? it looks like you are checking out the source for A but not for B, ie your root checks out \service but not \library

Comment: The root VCS checks out the solution (.sln). This solution has Project A and Project B referring inside it. However, as you can see Project A is inside a subfolder of the solution itself, whereas Project B is not in a subfolder, but in a whole different path. Basically, the reference to Project B in the solution file is **..\..\Library\MyLibrary\MyLibraryProject\MyLibraryProject.csproj**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have not set up your vcs roots correctly in TeamCity. Your example gives the folder structure of **d:\src\Service\MyService\MyServiceProject\MyServiceProject.csproj** and **d:\src\Library\MyLibrary\MyLibraryProject\MyLibraryProject.csproj**

you need to do one of two things:

If your projects are both help in some common folder which is in source control, then you need to set up your vcs root to checkout the folder containing both projects. In the example above you should checkout \src\ if this is a folder in your source control.

If this is not a folder in your source control then you need to set up 2 vcs roots for your build configuration one to checkout `Service` and one to checkout `Library`, then the source for both projects will be available on the build server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Samholder your suggestion helped. I configured two different VCS Roots and made sure the working directory paths are matching the solution.